# Keyboard show notification called twice using iOS11 Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard, ios11

I'm getting keyboard height using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` key like the following:

```
let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
print(keyboardHeight)
```

and if I tap `UITextView`, the keyboard comes up, and prints

```
258.0
```

then I press `⌘ + k`, the simulator connects hardware keyboard, hence software keyboard on the simulator goes down.

And if I press `⌘ + k` to make the keyboard up again, keyboardShow notification called twice and prints

```
216.0
258.0
```

Why is the keyboard show notification called twice and why `216.0` at first?

**Update**

This is my *entire* code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height

        print(keyboardHeight);
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

and the results shown if I press `⌘ + k` multiple times...

[result console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhxlI.png)

Comment: This is normal if you are having custom keyboard, you should create a variable to track and minus to get the correct height to move your view

Comment: @Tj3n what is custom keyboard? I use default simulator settings and just tried deleting all keyboard languages other than `English (U.S.)`, but results won't change.

Comment: seems like in simulator is different? you can try with real devices to see, pretty sure it will be the same result as the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure how you have declared your `observer`, but the following works fine in both Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 beta (iOS 11).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardHeight = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
    print(keyboardHeight)
}
```

**Update:**
Just tested your code and it complies and works fine, you must have something else that´s disturbing it.

**Output after testing:**
226.0
226.0
226.0
226.0
226.0
226.0

Comment: This is correct for apple keyboard, while the behavior above is apply to custom keyboard. I had to update my app before due to this.

Comment: I guess there's something else beside codes, thanks for the confirmation.